# Programing with Android studio 3.2 and making apk

Tags: android-install-apk

I'm writing an application with android studio 3.2.
Everything is okay when I install it on an emulator but when I make an apk and install it on real phone, it dosen't run!!

compileSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28

I want this app to be installed on android 4.1 or higher!

What changes are needed to run this app?

Comment: You can run the Android Studio debugger against a deployed APK to a handset. This will allow you to see logs, etc. There is not enough information here to help you -- it depends on _why_ it isn't running, and you don't say what research you have done. You might want to see [ask] for how to ask a question here.

Answer (score 0):

In your mobile open
setting > about mobile>Build number (press on it 7 times) 
after that return to 
setting > you will noticed that new choosing add (Developer options ) open it and make USB Debugging "active"

[image: 1]

**Press 7 times:**
[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

**Finally: open it and make the USB Debugging active**
[image: 5]